# Haskell print factorial

Tags: haskell, math, factorial

I've just started programming Haskell, basically because I was looking for a more mathematically powerful language then C#, and right now I'm very confused.

Right now I'm trying to simply find the the factorial of 4 and print that, this is what I wrote so far:

```
fact n = product [1..n]
main = do
   print fact 4
```

When I try to debug it i get

> Error:(3, 8) ghc: Couldn't match expected type `a1 -> t0' with actual type`IO ()'
>       The function `print' is applied to two arguments,
>       but its type`(a0 -> a0) -> IO ()' has only one
>       In a stmt of a 'do' block: print fact 4
>       In the expression: do { print fact 4 }

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think Haskell is "more powerful mathematically" than C# or anything else?  That's a naive way of calculating factorial.  Look into lngamma function for a better idea.

Comment: Why `lngamma` over `gamma`? OP doesn't want the natural logarithm of the factorial.

Comment: Duffymo, I understand C# can be mathematically powerful as well, but from what I've seen it takes less Haskell knowledge to make efficient code for what I need than in C#; since I'm dealing with factorials, numbers grow very much very quick, in C# I had it use Biginteger to handle that, and I wasn't very comfortable with it. Basically my final code does factorials and square roots. It checks for the existence of pairs of numbers where the first factorial +1 is the second squared. [4,5], 4!=24; 24+1=25; sqrt(25)=5.

Comment: Use lngamma because it defers overflow issues and it's natural for evaluating permutation and combination formulas.

Comment: Duffymo, English isn't my native language, I'm sorry if I lack the technical terms you find appropriate. I'll try to shape my vocabulary to what you find fit

Comment: Also, I did some small lookup on the lngamma right now (didn't go further because I'm in class) and I have to say I'm lost on its function. Could you provide an example of how to calculate factorials with it? Is lngamma(n)=(n-1)!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
main = do
    print (fact 4)
```

What GHC is seeing is `fact` and `4` being passed as separate arguments to `print`, but what you want is to apply `4` to `fact`, then apply that result to `print`.  You could also use

```
main = do
    print $ fact 4
```

The `$` operator doesn't do anything in itself, but it has a very low precedence, like how `+` is lower precedence than `*`, and it associates to the right, so you can write something like

```
f $ g . h $ m 1 $ 2 + 3
```

Instead of

```
f ((g . h) (m 1 (2 + 3)))
```